# A new look at the news!

Tags: vocabulary, translation

This phrase is supposed to mean "we are covering the news from a new perspective/from another angle. We don't analyse the news by following the major trends or opinions."

I could find a lot of example of the phrase "a new look at" on the web, but I'm just not sure if I can use it with "the news"

A new look at the news! is my try for the translation of the French phrase: "Un nouveau regard sur l'actualité"

Comment: I'd prefer *a new angle of the news* if you really mean seeing things differently.

Comment: I think *a new angle of the news* fails to communicate the intended idea.

Comment: @MaulikV The idiom would call for *a new angle **on** the news*.

Comment: @StoneyB I used it as it's used here: *The driving forces behind this transition are the power of the mass media as well as **a new angle of the** structural apparatus to obscure its power through the....* Would you mind enlighten me *a new angle of/on something* then?

Comment: @MaulikV That's a different *angle*, meaning "motive" or possibly "strategy", and it is an 'angle' adopted **by** the structural apparatus. It's an unusual use of 'angle' in this sense - I had to read the sentence three times, in context, before I could puzzle out what it meant. I note that the author, though very fluent, is not a native speaker of English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities—MaulikV's *new angle on the news*, jimsug's *new perspective on the news*, *new view of the news*, *new take on the news*—but I think your original is probably the best as a marketing slogan: neither stuffy nor slangy nor cutely echoic.

Comment: @Arone Thanks for your acceptance; but you may want to wait a few hours or a day to see if someone comes up with something better.

Comment: That's very noble of you!

Answer (score 0):

A suitable translation would be:

> A new perspective on the news.

Comment: Thanks but perspective is a word too long so I will stay with new look!